# Java application is not connecting to Database after hosting on vps

Tags: java, mysql, localhost, vps, plesk

I have created a Dynamic web application in java,jsp and connected to MySQL server using phpMyAdmin as localhost database server.
This is the code i have written in connection class:

```
static final String USER = "root";
static final String PASS = "";
Statement stmt = null;
static Connection conn = null;
String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/dbtest";
public static Connection getConnection() {

    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        System.out

        System.out.println("Connecting to database...");
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return conn;
}
```

And, While hosting this application on VPS (through Plesk parallel panel for windows) i have changed the DB_URL to my server ip address:port and uploaded on server using .WAR file.

When i am trying to print conn object to check if the connection is establishing with database i got the object value and connection was successful and all database operation are working well.

The issue i faced after hosting .war file is, conn object is returning null and my application gives 500 internal server error.

Can anyone suggest where iam going wrong and how to connect to database while hosting it.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you post the stacktrace?

Comment: Right now i have not added the code for stacktrace. But my application id working completely fine on my localhost. Why not after hosting it ?

Comment: Unless you post the stacktrace, it is difficult for us to know why.